# Sending a SIGHUP signal with PHP via shell_exec

Tags: php, bash, shell, ubuntu, signals

I am trying to send a **SIGHUP** signal to an external process using PHP. Currently, I am doing the following:

```
$pid = shell_exec('ps -ef | grep mosquitto | grep -v grep | awk \'{print $2}\'');
shell_exec('kill -s HUP $pid');
```

When I run "**php test.php**" from the command line, I have verified that the signal is sent to the correct process, as expected.

When I invoke the script by visiting **http://foo.com/bar/test.php**, the signal isn't sent, and shell_exec returns nothing.

For testing, I temporarily ran PHP with root permissions but had the same issue, so I assume this is not a permission issue.

Interestingly, **shell_exec** returns output for the **pwd** command and the **uptime** command to the browser, but not the **ls** command. But when run from the command line, shell_exec returns output from ls normally.

Is there another limitation of these commands that I'm missing?

Also, a few notes:

- Safe Mode is off
- error_reporting = E_ALL
- No functions are disables
- I have tried explicitly pointing to the binaries (Ex. /bin/ps and sh -c ps)

Comment: I must say the question was well asked, +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
echo shell_exec('(ps -ef | grep mosquitto | grep -v grep | awk \'{print $2}\') 2>&1');
```

and see if any errors are reported.  Also, you could try [`pgrep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep), [`pkill`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkill) or [`killall`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall) instead of messing about with `ps` and `grep`.

Alternatively, try just running `ps` and parsing its full output in PHP yourself.  ([`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and/or [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) may be useful for this.) 
And you can use [`posix_kill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php) instead of running an external `kill` program.

**Edit:** As per comments, it seems the actual issue was a missing or incorrectly set `PATH` environment variable.  One way to solve this issue would be to run `echo $PATH` in shell, copy the output and set `PATH` to the same value in PHP with [`putenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php).  Another solution is to use [`which`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_%28Unix%29) in shell to determine the full paths to `ps` *et al.*, and use those full paths in `shell_exec()`.

Comment: Your example code output: **sh: ps: not found sh: grep: not found sh: grep: not found**. I asked a friend, and he said that doing */bin/sh -c ps* should work, but similarly, that returns: **/bin/sh: ls: not found**

Comment: Your `PATH` environment variable is probably not (correctly) set when running under the webserver.  Either that, or you're running in some restrictive jail that simply won't let you access the `ps` executable.  Try running `which ps` in shell to find out the full path to `ps` and see if using that helps.

Comment: Seems to be the PATH. I modified my original line to use all absolute paths and it worked. Then I decided to use pkill instead - so much simpler. Please add the mention of the PATH to your answer, and I'mm mark it as accepted. Thanks!